# How to delay orders in pine script by numbers of minutes in 1hr timeframe?

Tags: delay, pine-script

I'm trying to delay entry orders by minutes.
ex: At 12:00 pm the macd line crossover signal line, but I wanna start entry.order at 12:02 pm.
So I tried the following code

```
//@version=4
strategy("delay2",calc_on_every_tick=true)

i_qtyTimeUnits  = input(2, "Quantity", minval = 0) 

int _timeFrom_ = na        
_timeFrom_ := i_qtyTimeUnits*60*1000

// Entry conditions.
fastLength = input(12)
slowlength = input(26)
signalLength = input(9)
MACD = sma(close, fastLength) - sma(close, slowlength)
signal = sma(MACD, signalLength)
delta = MACD - signal
bool goLong = delta>0
bool goShort = delta<0

float entrytime = na
float delaytime = na
entrytime := if goLong
    nz(entrytime[1], time)
delaytime := if entrytime>0
    nz(delaytime[1], entrytime+_timeFrom_)
delayElapsed = time>=delaytime

plot(entrytime)
plot(delaytime)
plot(time)

if goLong and delayElapsed
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Long")
    strategy.close('short', when = goShort)
```

I've plotted and checked that delayElapsed is true, but it just doesn't work,please help.

Answer (score 1):

I made a script that buys 2 minutes after a red candle has appeared. The buy is marked with an X.
[image: Image of x that is 2 min after a red bar]

There is a variable in pine script that is called **time**. The variable keeps track at the time where every candle is displayed. **time** is the number of milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970. For example, the current **time** when I'm writing this is *1625334502399*.

To determine the time when you should buy, you can add the number of milliseconds you want to the **time** and store it in a variable.

```
entrytime := time + 2 * 60 * 1000
```

So 2 minutes is equal to 2 * 60 * 1000 milliseconds. There are 1000 milliseconds on a second and 60 seconds on a minute.

You should store this value in a **var** variable because that value doesn't get erased after every bar.

```
var float entrytime = na
```

You can change to any timeframe and it will still buy 2 min after.

Here is the full code:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at 

https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © CanYouCatchMe

//@version=4
study("buying after 2 min", overlay=true)

delay_minutes = input(defval = 2, title = "Delay minutes")
var float entrytime = na //is used to store the time when it should buy

if (open > close and na(entrytime)) //Red candle and there is no current "entrytime"
    entrytime := time + delay_minutes * 60 * 1000 //"time" is the time in milliseconds where to candle appered. There is 1000 milliseconds on a second. And 60 seconds on a minute.

buy_condition = false
if (time >= entrytime) //Buys if the current time is greater or the same as the stored time.
    entrytime := na //Sets entrytime to na so it stops buying.
    buy_condition:=true

plotshape(buy_condition, style=shape.xcross, color=color.green, size=size.small) //Plotting an green "X" where it should buy

//Displaying the values "Data Window" on the right for Debugging.
plotchar(time, "time", "", location = location.top)
plotchar(entrytime, "entrytime", "", location = location.top)
```

Comment: It works! Really appreciate!
I think my problem is at line entrytime := if goLong   nz(entrytime[1], time)